# how to set date in second textbox according to first textbox date in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net application where i have two textbox for selection two date as Fromdate and EndDate. I have also two calender extender for both textbox whose Format is dd/MM/yyyy. If i select any date in First textbox "txtFromDate" using calender extender then it will calculate that if it is minimum 7 days smaller  than today date then second textbox will automatically set to 7 days after the date of first textbox date. If the difference between today date and first textbox date is less than 7 then second textbox should show today date in second textbox. For this i used the following code on first textbox textchanged event

```
DateTime dt1, dt2, dt3;

dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text);
dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Today);
dt3 = dt1.AddDays(7);
TimeSpan s = dt2 - dt1;
int x = (int)s.TotalHours;
x = x / 24;
if (x >= 7)
{
    txtEndDate.Text = dt3.ToShortDateString();
}
else
{
    txtEndDate.Text = dt2.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Here if i select 22/05/2018 then second textbox should show 29/05/2018 but it is showing 29-May-18. How to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried with DateTime.ParseExact("dd/MM/yyyy") ?

Comment: Amid all of this description, is the problem simply that `ToShortDateString()` doesn't output the format you want, and you want a custom output format for a date?  `.ToString()` on dates includes a custom format string: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly state your format instead of using ToShortDateString(). Use the following instead:

```
.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code :

```
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", YourDate);
```

Ref : http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: Good reference.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you are doing wrong here:

- `datetime.today` property gives you a DateTime object you need not to
  convert this again to DateTime.
- To get number of days between two dates you need not to get total hours then divide it by 24, you can simply use `TotalDays`property.
- Better to use Parsing instead for `Convert.ToDateTime` to avoid `FormatException`

So the modified code will be like the following:

```
var diffInDays = (dt2-dt1).TotalDays;   
if (diffInDays >= 7)
{
     txtEndDate.Text = dt3.ToShortDateString();
}
else
{
     txtEndDate.Text = dt2.ToShortDateString();
}
```

If the issue you are facing is the format of the date displaying in `txtEndDate` then you can use the `.ToString("Format-here")` as like other answers suggests. For example : `txtEndDate.Text = dt2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`